# Rails/ActiveRecord: How to write a "Maximum(...)" aggregation function when using Group By(...) the "Rails Way?"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I'm trying to accomplish is pretty straightforward. And conceptually, I know exactly what I want to do. I'm just having trouble with the ActiveRecord syntax.  (FWIW, my backend is Postgres, but I don't think that matters here?)

For the Classic Tetris World Championships (CTWC), I've been building a simple database that contains all matches players have ever played.  Tournaments happen annually and there's currently data in the system from 2012-2018.  The JSON REST API is here:

https://ctwc.herokuapp.com/api/matches

[image: Here's a sample of what the data looks like.]

I am currently trying to add a "Player Card" feature to the site.  Many recurring players have competed at CTWC over the years.  I wish to build a feature on the site that allows viewers to see stats for any given player.

[image: A mock-up of a "Player Card" looks like this.]

I'm working on the **"Participation" list**.  For a given player --say, "Quaid"-- I want to fetch from the DB the highest round that Quaid has ever advanced to in a given year.  But there's currently something wrong with my query; I think I'm using the "group by" function wrong.

Basically, I want to fetch all matches for "Quaid" and then group by the "Year" column; the aggregation function is I want to filter by "Maximum(Round)" -- (since I only care about fetching data for the highest round that Quaid advanced to in any given year).
Specifically, typed-out, here is my query that's *not* working:

```
Match.where("p1 like 'Quaid%' or p2 like 'Quaid%'").group('Maximum(matches.round)', :year)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to put the "Maximum" function in a select clause: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Comment: I think you want to `order by matches.round desc limit 1` instead

Comment: I think your question has a problem. If you want to fetch all matches then you can not group them by year:
`Match.select('max(round)').group(:year)`